# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be metric space, $A \subseteq X$, $f$ be a continuous map from $A$ to $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ be metric space, $A \subseteq X$, $f$ be a continuous map from $A$ to $Y$, then:

I, $A$ is compact, then $f(A)$ is compact;

II, If $A$ is bounded, then $f(A)$ is uniformly continuous;

III, Given $f$ is bijection, $A$ is bounded, $f(A)$ is compact, then $f^{-1}$ must be continuous.

I known that (I) is standard property of $f$, and (II) is false. But I'm very confusing with (III). Could you help me with this stuck?

Comment: What about $[0,1)\rightarrow S^1, t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$?

Comment: Could you explain clearly this suggestion? Thanks @archipelago

Comment: $[0,1)$ is a bounded metric space. $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon|z|\le 1\}$ is a compact metric space. I gave you continuous bijection between them. Now you can check, whether it suffices as a counterexample to your assertion III or not.

Comment: @archipelago: You should make that into an answer.

Comment: @archipelago: Could you show me more detail about your counterexample? Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you have issues with? If you are more concrete, I will try to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stefan H. suggested, I will post my comments as an answer.

Assertion III is wrong.
A counterexample would be the following:
$$\phi\colon[0,1)\rightarrow S^1,t\mapsto \operatorname{exp}(t2\pi i),$$ where $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon |z|= 1\}$ denotes the unit circle.
$[0,1)$ is clearly bounded, $\phi([0,1))=S^1$ is compact and $\phi$ is a continuous bijection and its inverse is not continuous, what shows, that $\phi$ serves as a counterexample to claim III.